# How do I use OpenConnect via Network Manager to connect to Juniper VPN?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openconnect

The more general question: *How do I pass arguments/switches to the client in Network Manager?*

In order to connect to a Juniper VPN using OpenConnect, I use the following command-line:
`sudo openconnect --juniper -u me vpn.juniper.example.com`

I've installed `network-manager-openconnect`, but it fails to connect (I get a "XML response has no "auth" node" message in the log window).

How do I configure the vpn client when using Network Manager?

**Update**
It may not be as simple as passing the `--juniper` switch.  I renamed the client and put a shell script in its place to call the client with the `--juniper` switch added and saw no difference in the behavior when trying to connect.  So the general question remains: how to configure the client when using Network Manager?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17.10, it seems to "just work" as long as you install not only network-manager-openconnect but also network-manager-openconnect-gnome .

The connection can then be configured via the settings UI: Under Network, VPN click the +, then choose Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN, then in the new connection dialog choose Juniper / Pulse OpenConnect and fill in the details.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The current stable network manager doesn't support this feature just yet but it is in developement. It seems it will be possible in the 1.4 version.

Source: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2016-July/003752.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Network Manager but you may get the same result with the following command line.

```
echo "PutHereYourPassWord" | openconnect --juniper -u userName --passwd-on-stdin --no-cert-check --authgroup=Users -i tun1 --useragent 'NetScreen-Remote 9.0' --os linux https://10.10.10.10
```

Note: Replace *userName*, *Users* and *tun1* with your *UserName* and corresponding *GroupName*. Also make sure to select correct *tunX* device. If your GW does UA sniffing, you may need to set a valid UserAgentString.

If you don't want passwords in CLI, remove corresponding flags, like so:

```
openconnect --juniper -u userName --no-cert-check --authgroup=Users -i tun1 --useragent 'NetScreen-Remote 9.0' --os linux https://10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score -1):

See the "Getting Help" section of the OpenConnect web site at http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/mail.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.