# Network Manager: Is it possible to pass CLI options to openconnect (in order to manually resolve the hostname)?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

Basically this question [has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/q/717364), albeit with a different flag/argument, and it's been a few years.

Since the people who administer my local network have apparently misconfigured IPv6, I need to manually specify an IPv4 address that I want my VPN gateway to resolve to. This can be done using
`openconnect --resolve=HOST:IP gateway`.

Is it possible to have Network Manager use the `--resolve=HOST:IP` argument? I tried adding the value pair to the `[vpn]` section of the `.nmconnection` file for the VPN, but it just ignored it (and yes, I did reload the file).

Answer (score 0):

You might have already figured this out by the absence of answers, but at the moment of writing network-manager-openconnect does not have an option to add the --resolve option to the list of command line arguments when running openconnect.

If you feel adventurous though, you could hack this in the source by:

```
# Get the build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager-openconnect
# Download sources
mkdir ~/nmo ; cd ~/nmo
apt source network-manager-openconnect
cd network-manager-openconnect-1.2.6/
# Edit nm-openconnect-service.c in lines 451 - 519
# Compile:
./configure
make
# Install:
mv /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service.bak
cp src/nm-openconnect-service /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service
# Restart networkmanager:
sudo service network-manager restart
```

For a quick hack your changes could look something like:

```
g_ptr_array_add (openconnect_argv, (gpointer) "--resolve=HOST:IP");
```

On line 480 or so.